# A distribution $u$ such that all of its derivatives are of order zero is smooth

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis

I'm reading Demailly's *Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry* In Section I.2.D.4 he uses the following fact: Suppose $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a distribution such that all of its derivatives are of order zero, i.e.

> for every compact $K \subset \Omega$ there is a $C_K > 0$ s.t. $ |\langle  u, \partial^\alpha f \rangle| \leq C_K \| f \|_\infty $ for all $f \in \mathcal{D}(K)$

equivalently we can say

> $u$ extends to a continuous linear map on $C^0_c(\Omega)$

Then the claim is that $u$ is actually given by a smooth function. I am not sure how to prove this and would appreciate any help or references.

These are my ideas so far:

- distributions of order zero are always given by integration agains a measure - I feel like combining this with the Lebesgue fundamental theorem  of calculus could give a proof for $n=1$.
- I know that if $u \in \mathcal{D}'$ has a *continous* derivative then $u$ is $C^1$, so it's sufficient to prove continuity of $u$ instead of smoothness. It seems like maybe every distribution with a zero-order second derivative must be continuous?

Comment: I think one can simply integrate the measure $\partial^{1,1,\ldots,1} u$ to find out that $u$ is continuous. An then repeat this argument for $\partial^\alpha u$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki it's definitely not quite that easy because $\operatorname{sign}' = 2\delta_0$ is of order zero but maybe integrating twice can work...

Comment: Ah, right, *measures* not *functions*. Yes, in this case integrating $\partial^{2,2,\ldots,2}u$ should work.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki can you explain why?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Also, what kind of integral are you talking about for $n \geq 2$? I wouldn't know how to take line integrals of a measure (and I actually doubt its possible?)

Comment: I attempted to give full details in my answer below; sorry for the delay. Taking integrals of measures with respect to a single coordinate is perfectly doable: one way is to interpret this in the sense of distributions, another way is to identify the measure with its distribution function and integrate the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Step 1.* With no loss of generality we may assume that $u$ is compactly supported (just multiply $u$ by a test function if it is not). Let $B = [-M,M]^n$ be a box that contains the support of $u$.

*Step 2.* Let $v = \partial^{(2,2,\ldots,2)} u$. Since $|\langle v, f\rangle| = |\langle u, \partial^{(2,2,\ldots,2)} f\rangle| \leqslant C \|f\|_\infty$, the distribution $v$ extends to a continuous linear functional on the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity, and hence $v$ corresponds to a finite complex-valued measure $\mu$.

*Step 3.* Now define $$\tilde u(x) = \int_{(-\infty, x_1) \times \ldots \times (-\infty, x_n)} (x_1 - y_1) \cdots (x_n - y_n) \mu(dy).$$ Clearly, $\tilde u$ is a continuous function, and by Fubini's theorem and the fact that $\int_t^\infty (s - t) f''(s) ds = f(t)$, we easily find that
$$ \int \tilde u(x) \partial^{(2,2,\ldots,2)}g(x) dx = \int g(y) \mu(dy) = \langle v, g\rangle = \langle u, \partial^{(2,2,\ldots,2)}g \rangle. $$
for every test function $g$.

*Step 4.* In particular, the distributional derivative $\partial^{(2,2,\ldots,2)} \tilde{u}$ is equal to zero in the complement of $B$. Since $\tilde{u}(x) = 0$ when $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n < -M$, we find that in fact $\tilde{u}(x) = 0$ in the complement of $B$.

*Step 5.* Since $\partial^{(2,2,\ldots,2)}g$ can be equal to an arbitrary test function $f$ on $B$, and both $u$ and $\tilde{u}$ are supported in $B$, we have
$$ \int \tilde u(x) f(x) dx = \langle u, f \rangle $$
for every test function $f$. That is, $u$ corresponds to a continuous function.

*Step 6.* Apply the above to the derivatives of $u$ to find out that $u$ is in fact smooth.

Comment: In Step 5, how do you know that $\partial^{(2, \dots, 2)}$ can be an arbitrary test function? E.g. for $n=1$ a positive function can't be the second derivative of a compactly supported function, right?

Comment: Oh I think I understand now, $g$ is defined on a set larger than $B$... So you just integrate f twice in every direction on $B$ and then fix everything outside $B$ so that the support is compact

Comment: Yes, that is right. I should have made it explicit in the answer.